# Remove Shadow which appears on expand of SimpleComboBox ext gwt

Tags: gwt, extjs, gwt2, gxt

I want to remove the shadow which appears on expand on SimpleComboBox.
I get the shadow as attached image.

below is my code

```
private SimpleComboBox<String> getSimpleComboBox(List<String> valuesOfComboBox, String objectToDisplay, boolean isVisible, String fieldLabel, boolean isTypeAhead, TriggerAction triggerAction, String id, boolean isShadowVisible){
        SimpleComboBox<String> comboBoxForUserAccount = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
        comboBoxForUserAccount.setVisible(isVisible);
        comboBoxForUserAccount.setShadow(false);

        if(valuesOfComboBox!=null)
            comboBoxForUserAccount.add(valuesOfComboBox);


        if(objectToDisplay!=null)
            comboBoxForUserAccount.setSimpleValue(objectToDisplay);
        comboBoxForUserAccount.setFieldLabel(fieldLabel);
        comboBoxForUserAccount.setTypeAhead(isTypeAhead);
        comboBoxForUserAccount.setTriggerAction(triggerAction);

        if(id!=null)
            comboBoxForUserAccount.setId(id);
        return comboBoxForUserAccount;
    }
```

Thanks[image]